# How to insert two split columns into two columns of table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a function which will take a string and a character as input and it will split string by this character and returns the column

```
DECLARE @strIndustryID varchar(MAX)='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,44,55,66,77,88'
DECLARE @strIndustryDescription varchar(MAX)='desc1|desc2|desc3|desc4|desc5|desc6|desc7|desc44|desc55|desc66|desc77|desc88'
DECLARE @COUNT INT=0
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@strIndustryID,',');
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@strIndustryDescription,'|');
```

and output by first Query

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
44
55
66
77
88
```

and from second query

```
desc1
desc2
desc3
desc4
desc5
desc6
desc7
desc44
desc55
desc66
desc77
desc88
```

now I want output like

```
<pre lang="vb">desc1
Col1 col2
2   desc2
3   desc3
4   desc4
5   desc5
.
.
.
.
```

and I want to insert these column into the table1 which has a column named col1 and col2

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @strIndustryID varchar(MAX)='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,44,55,66,77,88'
DECLARE @strIndustryDescription varchar(MAX)='desc1|desc2|desc3|desc4|desc5|desc6|desc7|desc44|desc55|desc66|desc77|desc88'
DECLARE @COUNT INT=0
SELECT a, b  FROM
(
SELECT a FROM dbo.Split(@strIndustryID,',') t1 CROSS JOIN 
SELECT b FROM dbo.Split(@strIndustryDescription,'|') t2
) AS main
WHERE a = REPLACE(b, 'desc', '')
```

Comment: Аnswer to a specific question. I generate data on my client and check this query.  SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT '1' AS t1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2'
UNION ALL
SELECT '3'
) T CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT 'desc1' AS t2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'desc2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'desc3'
) T1
) T3
WHERE t1 = REPLACE(t2, 'desc', '')

Comment: it is absolutly not that OP asks, and your fiddler differs from your post. You just youself create rows and join them (there is even no @strIndustryID in your fiddler). The question is how to make it from the string, split and dynamicly query, then pivot and get result

Comment: In the question it says that there is already split-function.